# asked for sudo password, post login to bash shell

Tags: bash, ssh, login, sudo

With 11.10 when any of my users with the bash shell login upon success they are asked to provide their sudo password e.g.

```
Last login: Fri Jan 20 19:13:36 2012 from x.x.x.x
[sudo] password for *user*:
```

However, using a different shell (viz. zsh) they aren't asked for their sudo password.

What's up?

**[edit: more info]**

So, of course it was obvious, but strange still.

**/etc/bash.bashrc**

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#execute firstlogin.sh only once
if [ ! -e /root/firstlogin_done ]; then
    if [ -e /root/firstlogin.sh ]; then
        /root/firstlogin.sh
    fi
    # This part should not be necessary any more
    # sudo dpkg-reconfigure -p critical console-setup &> /dev/null
    sudo touch /root/firstlogin_done
fi
```

The file is created just fine e.g.

```
$sudo ls -al /root/firstlogin_done
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 2012-02-29 16:04 /root/firstlogin_done
```

**[edit: is it a bug]**

So, I get why this happens. But, I don't get *why* this is happening. Is this a bug that I haven't updated?

Comment: Sounds like .profile is running something with sudo. Could you provide the content of `~/.profile` in your question?

Comment: But .profile is supposed to be run by all the shells. If this only happens in bash, it's likely something in ~/.bashrc or more likely /etc/bash.bashrc, as this late file will affect every user.

Comment: Not thinking of /etc/bash.bashrc **palmface**, nonetheless this is weird.

Comment: @JavierRivera, I don't know about viz (never heard of it), but zsh does not read .profile (unless it's invoked as sh). Bash, ksh and dash, to name a few, *does* use .profile though.

Comment: Sorry, **viz.=videlicet**: adverb *namely*; *in other words*.

Comment: Seems to be related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/409335. I can't fathom why anyone would think that was a good idea to use sudo in /etc/bash.bashrc. Not to mention the hashbang being completely wrong for a bash script.

Comment: @geirha Cool - thanks. I'd give you the correct answer if you answered! I guess I'll just wipe that file on my machines.

Answer (score 1):

The test fails since permission on `/root` is `700`. Hence, it uses sudo to clobber the file on every login.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, turning comment into answer.

This seems to be related to bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/409335. I can't fathom why anyone would think that was a good idea to use sudo in /etc/bash.bashrc. Not to mention the hashbang being completely wrong for a bash script.

However, /etc/bash.bashrc isn't really needed. Vanilla bash doesn't even read /etc/bash.bashrc; it's mainly a Debian/Ubuntu thing to have bash patched to specifically look for, and source, /etc/bash.bashrc when starting bash interactively.

Anyway, if you want the /etc/bash.bashrc that a fresh install will have, grab the sources and copy the etc.bash.bashrc file to /etc/bash.bashrc

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
apt-get source bash
sudo cp bash-4.2/debian/etc.bash.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc
```